# Suggested OO Design Pattern for a Query Builder

Tags: design, c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design

Essentially, I'm building a Query Builder (in C#, if that's relevant) which has this sort of interface, exposing more statically typed functions as the query gets more refined.

```
AnimalQueryBuilder
 - HasId(id): AnimalQueryBuilder
 - IsHealthy(): AnimalQueryBuilder
 - IsDog(): DogQueryBuilder
 - IsCat(): CatQueryBuilder

DogQueryBuilder
 - NumberOfPuppies(count): DogQueryBuilder
 - TailLengthBetween(start, end): DogQueryBuilder

CatQueryBuilder
 - AverageMeowsPerDayBetween(start, end): CatQueryBuilder
 - LikesMilk(): CatQueryBuilder
```

Essentially, starting from an AnimalQueryBuilder, I want to be able to do the following actions, to build a query in a fluent way:
`var builder = new AnimalQueryBuilder().IsHeathy().IsDog().NumberOfPuppies(4);`

This currently works but means that you can't structure the query like so:
`var builder = new AnimalQueryBuilder().IsDog().NumberOfPuppies(4).HasId(21);`
Because `HasId` is not exposed on the DogQueryBuilder

The way that I can get that to currently work is by having DogQueryBuilder and CatQueryBuilder inherit from AnimalQueryBuilder but then you'd be able to do actions which are invalid, like:
`var builder = new AnimalQueryBuilder().IsDog().NumberOfPuppies(4).IsCat();`

- Is there a design pattern that already exists for something like this?
- Should it just go down the first route of not exposing higher up functions (HasId) the more it gets refined and enforce that sort of order?

Comment: Why would you need to use `IsDog` or `IsCat` to determine if its a cat or a dog. You should already know what you're looking for an instantiate a `DogQueryBuilder` or `CatQueryBuilder` from the start.

Comment: So are you suggesting that you'd have `DogQueryBuilder` and `CatQueryBuilder` inherit from `AnimalQueryBuilder` and drop the `IsDog()` and `IsCat()` methods on AnimalQueryBuilder? That could work. I guess I liked the idea of being able to expand it so the different types of query builders are internal and consumers of the library just work with a top level `Query` object to generate any kind of query but with the static types for safety. i.e. future expansion to be able to do: `var query = new QueryBuilder().IsAnimal().IsDog().NumberOfPuppies(2).Build();`

Comment: @JamesB.: base classes in a class hierarchy which are not abstract are always a code smell.

Comment: Since you're using C#, are you familiar with using LINQ to build queries?  (just that you didn't mention it in the question)    Obviously it's not context-aware (which I assume is what you're trying to achieve here with the CatQueryBuilder), but it allows a either a fluent-style or SQL-style syntax to build "lazy" queries over anything which uses `IEnumerable` and tends to be quite expressive/readable.

Comment: @JamesB. Am I missing something? I don't see the problem you described, with [a sample code such as this (hosted on GitHub Gist)](https://gist.github.com/kinchungwong/cd3a0d75a0739d42085371d4045ced32).

Comment: @BenCottrell Yeah, they work well when consuming things but this is more of a problem about building a query. I've very briefly looked in to how you can write your own LINQ-supported queries but it looks a little overkill for what we need (or at least the guides I've seen on how to implement it?).

Comment: @rwong Yeah, that looks like what I'm looking for, we came up with a very similar method also using extension methods. It just seemed odd that you'd need to use extension methods for what really should be methods on the individual classes. Really appreciate your time spent creating a worked example. Do you know if there's a way to do this without needing extension methods?

Comment: @JamesB Ah I see now - would this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670650/how-to-apply-an-expression-tree-for-iqueryable  (Looking particularly at the top answer which uses Expressions and `ExpressionVisitor` to re-seat a query from an `Enumerable.Empty` onto a different IEnumerable)

Comment: In general, Fluent Interface cannot prevent a novice user from creating a nonsensical query such as `new QueryBuilder().HasId(10).HasId(20)` via the Intellisense code completion feature while the novice user is typing. It would have required either rigidity, or awkward class design, to prevent the novice user from specifying `HasId(id)` twice, with conflicting values. Surely the `.Build()` call can catch this, but can only do so at runtime, i.e. if the code that the user wrote ever gets executed.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good pattern for this. But it has nothing to do with OOP. But that’s fine. Not everything has to be about OOP.

Instead of always returning `this` try returning `Dog` or `Cat`. Then the legal methods are the available methods.

The pattern is called [internal Domain Specific  Language](https://www.infoq.com/articles/internal-dsls-java/) or iDSL. The idea is that returning different types lets you control what methods are available.

This lets you build a mini language just for object construction. It’s more powerful than the Joshua Block Builder pattern. It doesn’t simply simulate named parameters and produce an immutable object. iDSLs enforce construction rules statically. Helps those writing construction code avoid errors before they even run the code.

You’re not the first to throw a fluent interface at the SQL problem. A little library called [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) uses the same trick.

Creating an iDSL is hard work. You write many classes and get one useable object at the end of it.

If you have an an object whose construction is complicated and people have to write construction code for it often then an iDSL may be worth it.

Just don’t take this lightly. It’s work to create and it’s work to teach other programmers to use. Pick your battles wisely.

Comment: Actually, it's always called a *fluent interface.*  What gets returned doesn't matter; it's the method chaining technique that makes this what it is.  iDSL is just a name coined by that article writer to describe the end result of the technique.

Comment: Fluent interface has an end goal that is to reduce the friction of using an API via closely mimicking aspects of human natural languages, such as word order, position, grammar, attachment of detail, etc. Being an embedded DSL (eDSL), it has to design within the constraint of the host programming language. That is, create an OOP infrastructure that allows code to read fluently (by any programmer who reads English) and has valid syntax and exploits the language's niceties such as generics and real-time code suggestions at the fingertip.

Comment: @rwong iDSL and eDSL are two different names for the same thing.

Comment: @RobertHarvey method chaining is the structure. Fluent is the semantics. The goal is in the eye of the author.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few observations up front:

1. It looks like you're building a *predicate* rather than a full query that specifies fields and data sources.
2. Your design approach doesn't allow for predicates that are expression trees, e.g., with `and` and `or`.

As others have pointed out, it looks like you're somewhere between a fluent pattern and a builder pattern, but those can't fully account for the full range of predicates you might need.

Using a fluent design means that you can only further refine what you've already done. When using the builder design pattern in particular, it's uncommon to return something "smaller", e.g., returning `DogQueryBuilder` from `IsDog()`, rather than returning an updated `AnimalQueryBuilder`.

---

Another important consideration is the semantics of the query once you've built it.

For example:

- Will it construct a query string to pass to some DBMS?
- Will you need to extract metadata from it, e.g., a list of all fields it references?
- Will you ever need an expression that references separate data sources that have been joined elsewhere in the query? For example, "the dog and its owner have the same name."

The answers should ultimately determine what sort of implementation you go with. Comprehensive solutions might exist for a specific DBMS, but careless encapsulation could seriously complicate unit testing or swapping out the DBMS later on.

Such solutions generally also lack compile-time type safety (you won't find an existing solution that has `Cat` and `Dog` types), so it's usually helpful to still encapsulate calls to native query builders with something that's strongly typed.

---

Overall, I'd avoid the builder design pattern for the full predicate because only the simplest of predicates *aren't* expression trees.

In your example, when you say `.IsDog().NumberOfPuppies(4)`, `NumberOfPuppies` is predicated on `IsDog`. In plan language, this could mean at least two different things:

1. "*If it is* a dog, *downcast it to a dog* then make sure it has 4 puppies."
2. "*It must be* a dog. Given that it is, *downcast it to a dog* and make sure it has 4 puppies."

Neither of these interpretations is unreasonable, but it's unclear which it is. The second is clearly a refinement of the first, and could therefore take the form of "(it must be a dog) `and` (if it is a dog...)."

---

In summary, your current solution appears to narrow down conditions on specific data fields without allowing for multiple conditions to be specified. A fluent pattern is fine for targeting a particular field (sort of like a getter), but you will likely also need boolean operations.

For example:

```
Predicate
 - And(Predicate...): Predicate [static]
 - Or(Predicate...):  Predicate [static]
 - Not(Predicate):    Predicate [static]
```

Then let the individual builders each build a `Predicate`.

```
Predicate.And(
  new AnimalPredicateBuilder().IsDog().build(),
  new AnimalPredicateBuilder().AsDog().NumberOfPuppies(4).build(),
  new AnimalPredicateBuilder().HasId(21).build());
```

The member methods of `Predicate` will then depend on the various ways you'll need to use it, e.g., creating a query for SQLite, collecting a list of fields it references.

Comment: So essentially, there's a predicate (we've called "Filter") system behind the scenes which is used to build the SQL up and the QueryBuilder layer on top uses that and is an abstraction of that which narrows the data down and is more user friendly. It's not as flexible in terms of what can be queried but that's kind of the idea. Thanks for the extra ideas I haven't thought about and the context. I was really looking for how you'd be able to construct the builders to allow the methods in the examples without going down to the predicate level. Very useful thoughts though, thanks!